# Is OWASP Java Encoder Project enough to prevent reflected XSS?

Tags: java, security, xss, owasp, esapi

I've been reading articles about reflected XSS prevention. From what I understand, output encoding is the primary way to deal with reflected XSS. Some tools available would be the OWASP Java Encoder project and OWASP ESAPI. I have a java/JSP web application. I'm not sure if input validation should be also performed on the .jsp file when there is already input validation in the corresponding .java file. So I have the following questions:

1. Is OWASP Java Encoder project sufficient to prevent reflected XSS?
2. Do I need to do input validation on the .jsp file?
3. If 2. is a yes, would creating my own input validation functions or using the ESAPI Validator class be better?
4. If I have to use ESAPI, it means that I need to add ESAPI.properties and validation.properties. Given my project is an Ant project, where do I add these files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will address your individual questions in a moment, but first I want to suggest that you thoroughly read the [OWASP Cross-Site Scripting Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html). That will cover all the basics that you need to know, including discussions about defense-in-depth approaches. Now on to your specific questions.

1. **Is OWASP Java Encoder project sufficient to prevent reflected XSS?** *Answer:* If used correctly (that is you use the correct contextual encoder), for Java/JSPs, either the OWASP Java Encoder project or the ESAPI Encoder should be sufficient to prevent XSS in all but a few edge cases. Those edge cases are would including DOM-based XSS (so, technically, not 'reflected', I know) or cases where you have requirements that some HTML mark-up be allowed. (E.g., maybe in collecting user comments.) In those cases, you will want to also leverage HTML sanitizers such as the OWASP AntiSamy project or the OWASP Java HTML Sanitizer project.
2. **Do I need to do input validation on the .jsp file?** *Answer:* It is not absolutely necessary (assuming you use the output encoding correctly), but it wouldn't hurt. It is considered a part of the defense-in-depth strategy, especially in those tricky areas where mixed-encoding contexts are involved, such as rendering a URL in JavaScript. Along with input validation, Content-Security-Policy headers should are also strongly recommended, although CSPs are much easier to use in a green-field approach than in legacy applications.
3. **If 2. is a yes, would creating my own input validation functions or using the ESAPI Validator class be better?** *Answer:* In most cases you can probably do your own allow-list validation based on some simple regular expression matching. (Do not write the validation as block-lists though.) ESAPI Validation is probably more than you need and even as the ESAPI project co-lead, I personally wouldn't recommend it unless you are planning to use ESAPI for some other purpose (because it drags in a lot of transitive dependencies).
4. **If I have to use ESAPI, it means that I need to add ESAPI.properties and validation.properties. Given my project is an Ant project, where do I add these files?** *Answer:* You don''t *have* to use ESAPI, but if you do, where the `ESAPI.properties` and `Validation.properties` files go is not relevant to whether you use Ant or Maven or Gradle, etc. Look at class Javadoc for the ESAPI class [org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/latest/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultSecurityConfiguration.html) for details of how the `ESAPI.properties` and `Validation.properties` files are located.

Hope that helps answer your questions.

Comment: This answer is *ahem* canonical.  